# How from file.yaml in the root of app get data in several yaml's files which are in resources directory

Tags: java, yaml, app.yaml

How from file.yaml in the root of app get data in several yaml's files which are in resources directory. I tried use this  @{some-key data}:some value. However it doesn't work

Comment: can you provide more info/code?